Vivir a alguien por pendejo
I have read the following comment in https://qr.ae/psjO7A:

Vivieron al payaso por pendejo

This is a comment for this comic strip:

A boy is writing a diary: "En el pueblo hay un payaso que te asusta con tus mayores miedos. No le cuentes a nadie, mi mayor miedo es...
The evil clown shows up and says: - Que te regalen una Nintendo Switch! Muajajaja!
The boy gets the video-game, runs away and says out loud: Gracias, Payaso!
I can't find an appropriate meaning of "vivir" in this context in https://dle.rae.es/vivir.  I assume "vivir a alguien por pendejo" means "make a fool (out) of someone". Could someone confirm and tell me if this slang is specific to a country or region?

According to Diccionario de Americanismos, I think that your guessing is right and that such meaning is used mainly in Honduras
vivir

II.   1.  intr. prnl. Ho. Aprovecharse de alguien.
   2.    Ho. Reírse o burlarse de alguien.


TLDR: You.re right, the boy fools Pennywise, hence the commenter says that he "profited" the clown
En la polisemia que conozco (Argentina)

Vivir (a) = beneficiarse/aprovecharse (de) 
(se dice "vividor", a quien se aprovecha sistematicamenente de otros)

Por el uso de la palabra "pendejo", diría que el comentario podría ser de Mexico (o centro-américa) donde el término es muy corriente pendejo quiere decir "tonto, ingenuo")
La interpretación es que el comentario valora la sagacidad del chico —camuflando como un supuesto miedo su verdadero deseo— ante el payaso maligno para engañarlo y beneficiarse. Es el payaso malévolo,  (Pennywise) quien resulta burlado (por torpe pendejo, tonto, ingenuo, gil, gilipollas) por el otro personaje que "lo vivió" (se aprovechó) y usufructuó su estupidez
[La picardía ante el mal, aquí —por una vez— ingenuo y estafado]
